# how to Writing a static value returning method

Tags: java, methods, return, boolean

it is not returning and wants something to return 
whats wrong with it ? 
why when i want to get return from this Boolean method it asks me for return
i have just set the returns in the body of method

```
  public static Boolean winner(char[][] board) {
                if ((board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][0] == board[0][2])
                        || (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2])
                        || (board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[0][0] == board[2][0])
                        || (board[2][0] == board[2][1] && board[2][0] == board[2][2])
                        || (board[2][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[0][2])
                        || (board[0][2] == board[1][2] && board[0][2] == board[2][2])
                        || (board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[0][1] == board[2][1])
                        || (board[1][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][0] == board[1][2])) {
                    return true;
                } else if (true) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
                            if (board[i][j] == 'O' || board[i][j] == 'X') {
                                System.out.println("Game Over ");
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: You have `if` without `else` and no `return` after it.

Comment: `} else if (true) {` ?? Why not just `} else {` ?

Comment: If one player or the other has won, you return `true`.  You appear to intend to return `false` in the event that the board is full, though your logic there is faulty.  But what do you return, and where is the statement to return it, when neither player has yet won and the board is not yet full?

Answer (score 1):

The else if(true) is unnecessary. You just returned if the big if was true. Beyond that, you only return second block when the if embedded inside two loops is true. You need to return something after the loops.